# arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis crashes python

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, spatial-join

My two input feature classes are populated with data that intersect, the output feature class does not exist, and I have try: except: blocks with traceback, but python crashes here and doesn't get to any of that.

```
    outfc = r'C:\Temp\temp.shp'
    out_buff_fc = r'C:\Temp\out_buf.shp'
    out_line_fc = r'C:\Temp\out_line.shp'

    arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(target_features = out_buff_fc,
                               join_features  = out_line_fc,
                               out_feature_class = outfc)
```

What does it take to get this to run?

Comment: The error message might help. Do you have import arcpy?

Comment: add the error message

Comment: Windows tells me "Python has stopped working." I can't get anything out of the Windows error logs.

Comment: Sorry--I do have `import arcpy`, just trimmed it out of the code snippet though

Comment: how big are your datasets?

Comment: Do the 2 inputs have the same coordinate system?

Comment: @mfrancis you need to provide us more information about the input datasets if you want this solved.

Comment: @GISGe, I have processes that create the input shapefiles.  When python crashed, these remained.  Using them as inputs into the Spatial Join tool manually, the process runs to completion.  There are 8000 features in the buffer polygons and 15000 line features.  The input feature classes are in the same coordinate system.

Comment: I also neglected to say it starts to create the output, and creates an empty shapefile before bombing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the problem was is that I am using an ArcFM extension. Even when I am not using ANY of that functionality, some tools require me to check out an ArcFM license.